# Массив не известной длины

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Размеры двухмерного массива приходят по USB. Как задать с их помощью размер?

```
int8_t x = GetCharBuf();
int8_t y = GetCharBuf();
int arr[y][x];
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно выделить память динамически с помощью функции [malloc](http://www.hardline.ru/4/86/788/1166-122.html):

```
int** arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * y);
for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
  arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * x);
}
```

Не забудьте освободить память, когда она станет не нужна:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
  free(arr[i]);
}
free(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если ваш компилятор поддерживает массивы переменной длины - то можно именно так и использовать, как вы написали: https://ideone.com/lQfCcb

Но если нет - то надо использовать динамический массив. Вариантов два -

```
int **array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*y);
for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    array[y] = malloc(sizeof(int)*x);
```

Если это *действительно* С, а не С++ - приведение типа `malloc` не требуется.

Второй вариант -

```
int * array = malloc(sizeof(int)*x*y);
```

Но обращение к `array[i][j]` будет выглядеть как `array[i*x+j]`.